# Order characters in a string by their frequency in decreasing order

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Given a string, I want to sort it based on the decreasing frequency of its characters.
if the count is the same, the characters should be ordered alphabetically.

```
Input: "Programming"

Output: "ggmmrrPiano"

Explanation: 'r', 'g', and 'm' appeared twice, so they need to appear before any other character. 'g' appeasr before 'm' and 'r' hence why it appears first.
```

This is my code so far:

```
const sort_character_by_frequency = function(str) {
let map={}
for(let i=0;i<str.length;i++){
 map[str[i]]?(map[str[i]]+=1):(map[str[i]]=1);
}

return Object.keys(map).sort((a, b) => return {

  if(map[a] === map[b]){
    return a.charCodeAt(0)-b.charCodeAt(0);
  }
  else return map[b]-map[a];

  }).reduce((str, key)=>{
  return str+=key.repeat(map[key])
},"")
};
```

I'm getting an "unexpected token" error at the start of the Objects.keys(map).sort() statement. I can't for the life of me figure out what is wrong.

Any help or insight into this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `(a, b) => return` is invalid syntax.

Comment: Also, do yourself a favor and don't use the keyword `map` for your var name.

Comment: See [Arrow Function Expressions: Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Syntax).

Comment: @jmargolisvt `map` is not a [reserved keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords).

Answer (score 3):

A way of doing it is by leveraging the language capabilities, like so:

```js
let str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Consectetur adipiscing elit,"

let newStr = 
  str.split('').sort().join('').match(/(\w)\1*/g).sort(
    (x, y) => y.length - x.length
  ).join('')

console.log(newStr)
```

It [splits](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string into an array, [sorts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) it by value and [joins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) it into a string which is [matched](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to the a regular expression `/(\w)\1*/g` returning an array with all the groups of characters. In turn, said array is sorted by the length of its elements and joined into a string again.

Answer (score 0):

Solved  in C++

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

struct Node
{
    char ch;
    int total;
    Node(char ch, int total){
        this->ch = ch;
        this->total = total;
    }
};


bool mySort(Node a, Node b){
    if(a.total == b.total){
        return a.ch < b.ch;
    }
    return (a.total > b.total);
}

std::string solve(std::string &s){
    std::vector<Node> nodes;
    std::map<char, int> m;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::map<char,int>::iterator it = m.find(s[i]);
        if(it != m.end()){
            // Exists
            Node *node = &nodes[it->second];
            node->total++;
        }else{
            Node node(s[i], 1);
            nodes.push_back(node);
            m[s[i]] = nodes.size() - 1;
        }
    }

    std::sort(nodes.begin(), nodes.end(), mySort);

    std::string str = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < nodes[i].total; ++j)
        {
            str += nodes[i].ch;
        }

    }

    return str;
}

int main()
{
    std::string s = "Programming";
    std::string result = solve(s);
    std::cout << "Result is: " << result;

    return 0;
}
```

For JavaScript

```js
var s = "Programming";
var map = {};
var nodes = [];

for(var i = 0; i < s.length; ++i){
 var it = map[s[i]];
 if(typeof it !== "undefined"){
   //exist
    nodes[it].total ++;
  }else{
   map[s[i]] = nodes.length;
    nodes.push({total: 1, ch: s[i]});
  }
}

nodes = nodes.sort(function(a, b){
 if(a.total < b.total){
   return 1;
  }
  if(a.total == b.total){
   if(a.ch < b.ch){
     return -1;
    }else{
     return 1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
});

var result = "";
for(var i =0; i < nodes.length; ++i){
 var node = nodes[i];
 for(var j = 0; j < node.total; ++j){
   result += node.ch;
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: "Prroggammin" is the result I get when I run your algorithm.

Comment: i tested with Javascipt via console result is: ggmmrrPaino

Comment: also same result Result is: ggmmrrPaino for c++